# Please tell where is config.inc.php file is located for wordpress phpmyadmin

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin

I am trying to create new database for wordpress site in php my admin but whenever i click on Databases it shows no previlges also i cannot find config.inc.php file plz tell where it is located